# how to write quote / single quote punctuation to file with Linux command

Tags: linux

I want to write " or ' into a file with `ECHO "\" " >> file.txt` command in linux, but it showed me output redirector operator `>`, instead of writing the " into file. And I am not able to exit > status and back to

> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$

Is there anyone know how to insert single quote or quote into a file and exit >? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape it using a `backslash`.

Try this:

```
echo \' >> a.txt 
echo \" >> a.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Jaliene Huang, 
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)